# How do I set the default coordinate system for the line tool in Autocad?

Tags: autocad

On my laptop, I set a variable that makes it so the line tool defaults to Cartesian coordinates. On my desktop, I can't seem to find the variable name. I have been searching for hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable is DYNPIFORMAT.

> Controls whether pointer input uses polar or Cartesian format for coordinates.
>
> This setting applies only to a second or next point.
>
> 0 Polar
>
> 1 Cartesian

(From: https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad-lt-for-mac/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/AutoCAD-LT-MAC/files/GUID-03D36D36-D734-43C3-BA4D-EA68C573F73C-htm.html)